# How do I not reinitialise my local variable which is auto-configured via an external bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

ClientApplication.java

```
    @Autowired
    Config_map trial;

    public  static HashMap<String,String> myMap;

    ClientApplication(Config_map trial){
        this.myMap=trial.returnMAP();
        System.out.println("done done"+myMap);
    }
```

Config_map.java

```
    @RefreshScope
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties()
    public HashMap<String,String> returnMAP() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
```

So my constructor is initialised after autowiring my trial object. My trial object is used to retrieve all properties in the form of a map from a .properties file. It works fine when I access an endpoint and am able to access the map. The problem occurs when I hit /actuator/refresh and then hit any endpoint. After hitting the refresh the constructor is called again and I can see the println statements. Why is that happening is there a way by which my map in my ClientApplication does not get reinitialised every time I hit a specific endpoint after /refresh?

Answer (score 1):

I have the following reference for your usecase:

@RefreshScope works (technically) on an @Configuration class, but it might lead to surprising behavior. For example, it does not mean that all the @Beans defined in that class are themselves in @RefreshScope. Specifically, anything that depends on those beans cannot rely on them being updated when a refresh is initiated, unless it is itself in @RefreshScope. In that case, it is rebuilt on a refresh and its dependencies are re-injected. At that point, they are re-initialized from the refreshed @Configuration).

Comment: Alright got it makes sense! There is no problem with the dependencies reinitialising after @refresh on the configuration, the issue is my dependencies are reinitialised when i hit an endpoint after refresh... is there a workaround such that only the bean gets refreshed and my dependencies are not reinitialised every time i hit an endpoint(after refresh)